# Attaching Visual Studio 2012 to Matlab 2014a(32 bit): tbb.dll

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, tbb

I am encountering a strange problem.
1>I open visual studio 2012
2> I open matlab 2014a (32 bit)
3> I try "Attach to process" and put the matlab process from the list displayed in the process window that comes up.

What happens is I get window in visual studio saying

"Loading symbols for tbb.dll from:
z:\itt\branch_tbb40\tbb\1.0\build\fxeowin18vc10_32_release
Attempting to cancel will disable furhter symbol loading"

and hangs.

The issue is "z:\itt\branch_tbb40\tbb\1.0\build\fxeowin18vc10_32_release" does not exist in my computer. How come visual studio is trying to load from this folder ? where is it getting its information from.

Also the tbb.dll is in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win32" folder which I have put in the path environment variable. 
How come visual studio is not looking there.

It would be very kind if someone gives my some pointer to fix the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there an actual pdb file in C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win32 ?

Comment: there is no tbb.pdb file in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\win32" the only thing i have is tbb.dll

Answer (score 1):

`z:\itt\...` is the path where the pdb was when the dll was originally built from source, possibly on a build server or so but definitely not on your machine so it's normal you don't have that directory.

When loading symbols for a dll, the debugger will also look for the original pdb path (which is stored in the dll) apart from considering various other paths. As far as I know the PATH is *not* used when [looking for pdbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx) so don't bother adding directories to it for that reason. The directory where the dll is located is searched, but you probably don't notice because it flashes by quickly in VS. (note if you want to see all places where VS searches you could use [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor)).

As to why VS hangs: no idea. But does it really hang 'forever' (as in not responding + corresponding dialog)? One possibility would be that z: is mapped as a network drive and VS is waiting for a response from it, which should timeout after a while.

Comment: is there a way to of this. if I hit "cancel" matlab, visual studio everything becomes un-responsive and I have to kill them through task-manager. I have attached visual studio to matlab before (in other computers) and did not encounter this problem. is there any way i can resolve this issue ?

Comment: There is likely a way to resolve this but I cannot possibly guess how since you provide no additional information. For instance, do you have a z: drive or not? Alternative: go to Tools->options->Debugging->Symbols, click *specify excluded modules* and add tbb.dll there.